# How to add similar key value in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

This is the array of data:

Input Data:

```py
list1 = [{'user': 1, 'coins': 2}, {'user': 18, 'coins': 8}, {'user': 1, 'coins': 1}, {'user': 3, 'coins': 1}, {'user': 5, 'coins': 1}, {'user': 7, 'coins': 0}, {'user': 18, 'coins': 0}]
```

Expected Outcome:

```py
list2 = [{'user': 1, 'coins': 3}, {'user': 18, 'coins': 8}, {'user': 3, 'coins': 1}, {'user': 5, 'coins': 1}, {'user': 7, 'coins': 0}]
```

So, there will be `list1`, and we have to add the coins to similar `user` which can be identified by user key value. If user key have similar value that is 1 (in above case) then coins of both or multiple user must be added making it a total sum of that user coins.

In above example, we can see that user with 1 as value in 2 different dict got added and total sum was given in list 2.

Comment: did the answer work for you? Since you seem to have never upvoted or accepted an answer on your questions, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as intermediate data object:

```py
import collections
dd = collections.defaultdict(int)
for d in list1:
    dd[d['user']] += d['coins']
list2 = [{'user': user, 'coins': coins} for user, coins in dd.items()]
```

or similary, using a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object:

```py
cntr = collections.Counter()
for d in list1:
    cntr[d['user']] += d['coins']
list2 = [{'user': user, 'coins': coins} for user, coins in cntr.items()]
```

Comment: You probably don't want to make that list at the end. The existing data structure simply looks wrong, and your transformation fixes it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I'm not really sure what you mean. Is this comment directed to me or to the OP?

Comment: A bit of both. I'm suggesting that `list2` is code smell and should probably be omitted.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, okay, I agree on that, but I don't want to judge the code in the question. OP could have reasons to want such a data structure and I tried to provide an answer. This could also serve as an example for other scenarios. However, for the given example code, without more context, it would indeed make much more sense to use a dictionary or Counter and forget about the list :-)